# Is there a safe way to animate the scrolling of a UIScrollView manually?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiscrollview

I have very custom animation needs of a UIScrollView that are much more than just deceleration.

What's the safest way to animate the contentOffset or bounds of a UIScrollView without causing interference with the default animation behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create an animation block, you can animate the tableView movement by setting contentOffset directly 'tablView.contentOffset = foo' (or with animation off 'tableView setContentOffset:foo animated:NO'). This decouples the tableview's own internal animation.